# Automator wifi specific backup

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, automator

I am wanting to automate the running of a weekly backup of certain folders on my Mac to the cloud when I am connected to my home network.

Scenario:

> Check wifi network name
>
> If 'home' then perform backup
>
> else exit

I have created a calendar event to trigger an automator script.

I currently have two bash scripts

1. to determine the wifi network that i am connected to
2. to perform the backup (using rclone)

The part i am struggling with is the If, Then, else part.

Bash script 1:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}'
```

Attempt at applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    if input is not ("home") then error number -128
    
    return input
    
end run
```

Bash Script that should run on detection of home network:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rclone/1.52.1/bin/rclone copy "Source" Remote:folder
```

Both bash scripts work but i am stuck on the conditional part.... any help gratefully received.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your entire right-side pane in Automator showing all the code?

Comment: If you only have the DEFAULT applescript `on run {input, parameters} // return input // end run`, does the word ` home` appear in the results tab of the applescript after you run the full script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your command, I get the following

```
❯ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}'
 Home
```

You will notice there is a tiiiiiiiiny space prior to `Home`.  The text is actually `<space>Home`.

Your issue is in the `awk` command.

When you split the text            `SSID: Home` by the `:`, `$1` becomes            `SSID` and `$2` becomes  `Home`. (again, note the spaces).

Your input to the applescript is looking for `Home`. `Home` does not match  `Home`.

**Be mindful of both Spacing AND Capitalization.**

---

Secondly, `input` is a `list`, not a string.  So `input is not ("home")` will always run because you are comparing it to a string.

You must typecast `input` as a `string` if you wish to compare it to a `string` such as  `home`.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if (input as string) is " home" then
        tell application "System Events" to display dialog "You are home."
    end if
    return input
end run
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I have run the command in the terminal and copied and pasted the name exactly as it is returned so it should be looking for exactly the right thing.

However it still doesn't seem to work. If I have the line
`if input is not (" Home") then error number -128`
it always seems to exit....
if i remove the `not` and just have
`if input is (" Home") then error number -128`
no matter what it completes the  script.....

Is there something else wrong with the script?

Comment: Really appreciate the help, I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out why I can't write a simple script.

Comment: perhaps I am not passing the output from the bash script as input to the applescript correctly? set to run as /bin/bash and passinput is set to stdin but it doesn't make any difference if i set it to 'as arguements'/

Comment: " I am tearing my hair out"... I can see that friend.  Slow down. Have you just tried a simple `echo input` (or the applescript equivalent) to ensure you ARE getting ` Home` to the script?

Comment: As a general rule, always use some method to trim _leading/trailing spaces_ so there are no ambiguities about what's being compared. Instead of worrying about a _leading space_, in this use case, set the _delimiter_ to account for it, e.g. `-F': '`, then just test for `Home` without a _leading space_.

Comment: user3439894 is correct. As always, sanitize input to your function, so the first place you should validate is within the AppleScript. Unfortunately, there's no built in function to do that, so you are better off doing it at the Shell Script layer. You can use user3439894's option or append a `| sed 's/^ //g'` to the end of the shell command. There's no right way, but there is a few wrong ways.  Experiment around with different ways in different projects.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have learned a lot about automating in the process!